# What is this mysql error? ²»ÖªµÀÕâÑùµÄÖ÷»ú¡£

Tags: mysql, unicode, phpmyadmin

I got the code from MySQL under Unicode(utf8) encode. Anyone know the original message?

> ## 2002 - php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ²»ÖªµÀÕâÑùµÄÖ÷»ú¡£
>
> The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: what is your connection string??

Comment: I was talking about encoding issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that's probably supposed to be:

```
不知道这样的主机。
```

which appears to mean something to the effect of "unknown hostname", but it got displayed using the ISO8859-1 character encoding instead of the intended GB2312.

I figured this out by saving the text of the error to a file (encoded, incorrectly, as UTF-8), then running:

```
cat errormessage \
  | iconv -f utf-8 -t iso8859-1 \
  | iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8
```

(ISO8859-1 was an educated guess, as most incorrectly encoded text is being displayed as that encoding. Based on your profile, I guessed the intended encoding was probably a Chinese encoding; after BIG5 gave me nonsense, I tried GB2312, which yielded some text that Google Translate was halfway able to understand.)

Comment: The question is how you make it? You just try all encoding?! By chance you found it?! Well, I can't find the ISO8859-1 in Google Chrome; but, by your hint, I tried it in PHP, it seems work. well, I mess up again :S

Comment: I found it, here is the steps: